# Generics inside a delegate or datasource

Tags: ios, generics, swift, protocols

I'm trying to find a solution to use generics inside a `delegate` or `dataSource` protocol.

For now I've declared the following `protocol`:

```
@objc protocol PageViewControllerDelegate {
    optional func pageViewController(pageViewController: PageViewController, didScrollToViewController viewController:UIViewController)
}
```

What I want is a generic protocol like this:

```
@objc protocol PageViewControllerDelegate {
    typealias T
    optional func pageViewController(pageViewController: PageViewController, didScrollToViewController viewController:T)
}
```

This results in the following problems:

1. As I've declared a `typealias`, I can't use `@objc` anymore and the optional tag
2. When I declare the protocol as a property of my non generic class, I get the error *"protocol can only be used as a generic constraint because it has self"*

I've declared the property as followed:

```
class PageViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    var delegate:PageViewControllerDelegate?
}
```

Any help would be welcome.

Oh and, I'm just using this `PageViewController` case as an example to find out if this is possible. I'm not looking for another way to use the `UIPageViewController` for example.

Answer (score 0):

First I believe that you intended

```
protocol PageViewControllerDelegate {
    associatedtype T: UIViewController
    func pageViewController(pageViewController: PageViewController, didScrollToViewController viewController: T)
}
```

although this is an old thread with an older version of Swift, so a `typealias` may have been utilized in protocols.

It appears that associated types are not supported in Objective-C, so there is no way around providing both an optional protocol implementation and an associated type; however, you can effectively create an optional implementation by leveraging  a protocol requirement that is given a default implementation through an extension as shown:

```
protocol PageViewControllerDelegate {
    associatedtype T: UIViewController
    func pageViewController(pageViewController: PageViewController, didScrollToViewController viewController: T)
}

extension PageViewControllerDelegate {
    // Does nothing on its own. Note that because this method is a requirement of the protocol, dynamic dispatch is used instead of static dispatch
    func pageViewController(pageViewController: PageViewController, didScrollToViewController viewController: T) {}
}

class MyClass: PageViewControllerDelegate {
    typealias T = UIPageViewController

    // No compile-time errors for an effectively optional method

    // Custom implementation
    //func pageViewController(pageViewController: PageViewController, didScrollToViewController viewController: UIPageViewController) {
    //
    //}
}
```

You are not allowed to declare a variable to be the type of a protocol with associated types because the declaration is ambiguous. This is similar to how you are not allowed to simply declare a variable to the `Array` type in Swift: there is no single `Array` type because of its generic parameters. Associated types are the protocol equivalent of the generic arguments of generic types. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32741043/cant-call-extension-method-on-generic-array-class-when-element-type-is-a-protoc/62138354#62138354) for further explanation of some other protocol features.

You could try something along these lines

```
protocol PageViewControllerDelegate {
    associatedtype T: UIViewController
    func pageViewController(pageViewController: PageViewController<Self>, didScrollToViewController viewController: T)
}

extension PageViewControllerDelegate {
    func pageViewController(pageViewController: PageViewController<Self>, didScrollToViewController viewController: T) {}
}


class PageViewController<Delegate: PageViewControllerDelegate> : UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    private var delegate: Delegate?
}

final class MyDelegate: PageViewControllerDelegate {
    typealias T = UIPageViewController

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: PageViewController<MyDelegate>, didScrollToViewController viewController: UIPageViewController) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

The only drawback is that the delegate must be marked `final` with the use of `Self` in the protocol method.

This is an old thread, and by now you may already be well aware of these capabilities and features. Hopefully this helped regardless.