# Can't call extension method on generic Array class when element type is a Protocol [Swift]

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, protocols

The following fails as per the error message quoted in the comment. It has been boiled down to the bare minimum, so the code below has no apparent practical value. I'm just trying to get a handle on the truly bizarre (in my opinion) error message. The reason I want to declare the array as `[P]` and not `[S]` is for the usual run-time polymorphism of the array contents.

```
protocol P {
    func sp()
}

struct S: P {
    func sp() {}
}

extension Array where Element: P {
    func am() {}
}

func t() {
    let goodA = [S]()
    goodA.am() // No problem

    let badA = [P]()
    badA.am() // Error: '[P]' is not convertible to 'P'
}
```

Comment: I *think* there was a similar question, but I haven't found it yet. The answer was that a protocol does not conform to itself.

Comment: Or apparently, any parent protocols (so that `protocol Q: P {}` does not solve anything); am I missing a deeper point about conformance that `where` clauses may only be satisfied by concrete types?

Answer (score 1):

Protocol declarations define new independent types. While they do behave differently than classes, enums, and structs, they can act as the type for a variable or property (provided there are no associated type constraints, but hold on). For instance

```
protocol MyProtocol {}
let myConst: MyProtocol // myConst has type `MyProtocol`
```

In a protocol extension with a generic where clause, there are two different ways to constrain the generic type in question: either with `:_` or `==`. There is a difference between the two.

**Use of :_**

The colon specifies that the generic type is something matching the type or protocol specified. It can be read as 'inherits from' or 'conforms to'. For example, anything specified in the extensions apply only when the associated type conforms to `Equatable` or inherits from `SomeClass`

```
protocol AnotherProtocol {
    associatedtype MyType
}

class SomeClass {}

extension AnotherProtocol where MyType: SomeClass {}
extension AnotherProtocol where MyType: Equatable {}
```

**Use of ==**

The `==` operator in a generic where clause specifies that the generic type is *exactly* the type specified and no other. The code below gives a compile-time error

```
class CustomType {}
class CustomTypeII: CustomType {}
class MyClass: AnotherProtocol { typealias MyType = CustomTypeII }

extension AnotherProtocol where MyType == CustomType {
    func myFunc() {}
}

let instance = MyClass()
instance.myFunc() // Error: `CustomTypeII` is not the same type as `CustomType`
```

The `==` operator **cannot** be used to constrain a generic type to a protocol with associated types. The compiler will complain that the protocol has an associated type requirement.

```
protocol ThirdProtocol {}

extension ThirdProtocol where Self == AnotherProtocol {} // Error: `AnotherProtocol` has associated type requirements
```

In essence, the specification is ambiguous: there is no single `AnotherProtocol` type, much in the same way that there is no single `Array` type. The associated type in a protocol acts similarly to the generic arguments of a generic type. Here, the use of a colon is needed to specify that the generic type 'is some' `AnotherProtocol` type (opaque types follow from the need to specify a specific 'type' of a protocol with associated type constraints, but that is beyond the question).

**Your extensions**

The extension of `Array` applies only to array instances whose elements are some type that conforms to the protocol type `P`, which does not apply to arrays whose elements are the type `P`. Protocols not conforming to themselves is akin to classes not inheriting from themselves.

This is an old thread, but hopefully this helped.

Comment: This is a great answer! Maybe just add a direct solution to the OPs problem. For example, they could create a `protocol PParent {}`. Then, all they have to change is have `P` inherit from `PParent` and change the where clause to `where Element: PParent`. Nice explanation though, +1!