# iOS - Error with Protocols and generics when used as a dependency

Tags: ios, swift, generics, associated-types

I have a protocol ContainerService whose `sessionService` object is used in our network layer. I'm trying to inject the `sessionService` into an object that encapsulates the network layer. I used a base protocol to avoid the error

```
Protocol `SessionService` can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

This issue was fixed by adding

`var sessionService: SessionServiceBase { get set }`

as a requirement for `ContainerService`

However when I try to use `sessionService` as a property of TestClass, I come across the same error. Also I ran into another error 
`Member connectSession cannot be used on value of Protocol type`SessionService`; use a generic constraint instead`

Here is a sample code

```
protocol NetworkService: AnyObject {
    var sessionService: SessionServiceBase { get set }
}

protocol SessionServiceBase: AnyObject { }
protocol SessionService: SessionServiceBase {
    associatedtype T: Tokenable
    func connection(credential: T)
}
protocol Tokenable { 
    var token: String { get set }
    var key: String { get set }
}

struct CustomToken: Tokenable {
    var token: String
    var secretKey: String
}

class CustomSessionService: SessionService {
    func connection(credential: CustomToken) {
        print(credential.token)
    }
}

class CustomNetworkService: NetworkService {
    var sessionService: SessionServiceBase = CustomSessionService()
}

class ConsumerClass {
    var networkService: NetworkService?
    init(networkService: NetworkService) {
        self.networkService = networkService
    }

    func test(){
        let tokens = CustomToken(token: "", key: "")
        guard let sessionService: SessionService = networkService?.sessionService as? SessionService else {
            return
        }
        sessionService.connection(credential: tokens)
    }
}
```

Is there a work around this generic error issue? If this code is run on a playground there will be two error inside `test` func.
1. 
`Protocol SessionService can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

2.
 `` Member `connection` cannot be used on value of protocol type `SessionService`; use a generic constraint instead. ``

Comment: TestClass needs to conform to SessionService. You need also to define what is the associated type `typealias Token = TestToken`

Comment: `TestClass` has an instance of `sessionService` object which conforms to `SessionService` protocol

Comment: @LeoDabus I updated the question with more information

Comment: NetworkService is a protocol not a type

Comment: Think
 about Swift native protocols. You don't create a property in your class or struct of type StringProtocol, FloatingPoint or BinaryInteger

Answer (score 0):

The `SessionService` protocol can only be used a generic type constraint because the associated type implies that there is not one specific type of `SessionService` but any number, analogous to how there is not one `Array` type in Swift. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32741043/cant-call-extension-method-on-generic-array-class-when-element-type-is-a-protoc/62138354#62138354) for some more details about this.

For instance, we could not guarantee that the `sessionService` instance actually connected with a `CustomToken` because its associated type is not specified. Hence, Swift does not allow it.

There are some alternatives though. At some point you have to make something concrete. To implement what you may be looking for with generics, observe the following:

```
// Protocols

protocol SessionService: AnyObject {
    associatedtype T: Tokenable
    func connection(credential: T)
}
protocol NetworkService: AnyObject {
    associatedtype Service: SessionService
    var sessionService: Service { get set }
}
protocol Tokenable {
    var token: String { get set }
    var key: String { get set }

    // Provide an initializer to require that a token can be made in this way
    init(token: String, key: String)
}

// Custom types

class CustomSessionService: SessionService {
    func connection(credential: CustomToken) {
        print(credential.token)
        print(credential.doSomething())
    }
}

class CustomNetworkService: NetworkService {
    var sessionService: CustomSessionService = CustomSessionService()
}

struct CustomToken: Tokenable {
    var token: String
    var key: String
    var secretKey: String = ""

    init(token: String, key: String) {
        self.token = token
        self.key = key
    }

    var myStr: String = "aaa"
    func doSomething() -> String { myStr }
}

// Type erasure

class AnyNetworkService<ServiceType>: NetworkService where ServiceType: SessionService {
    typealias Service = ServiceType
    var sessionService: ServiceType

    init(service: ServiceType) { self.sessionService = service }
    convenience init<T: NetworkService>(networkService: T) where T.Service == ServiceType { self.init(service: networkService.sessionService) }
}


// Combines everything

class ConsumerClass<Service: SessionService> {
    var networkService: AnyNetworkService<Service>?
    init(networkService: AnyNetworkService<Service>) {
        self.networkService = networkService
    }

    func test() {
        let tokens = Service.T(token: "asd", key: "fff") // create a token for the specific Service passed in
        guard let sessionService = networkService?.sessionService else { return }

        sessionService.connection(credential: tokens)
    }
}

// Example

let networkService = CustomNetworkService()
let consumer = ConsumerClass<CustomSessionService>(networkService: .init(networkService: networkService))
consumer.test()
```

The last line will call `connection(credential:)` in `CustomSessionService`.

The only potential drawback is that there is no longer a single `ConsumerClass` but instead many. Also, a `Token` created in `test()` cannot have its other properties assigned for the its type is not known to you. However, given its flexibility for using different `Network` and `SessionService` concrete types, it may be of use.